# Not getting a new line when using use "\n" in PHP

Tags: php, html, newline

I am trying to use `\n` in PHP to get a new line on my website, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['selected'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['selected']; 
    // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "\n";
    echo $selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
```

Comment: If you're echoing to a web page you will need to use `<br />`

Comment: `\n` only affects the source (when you inspect), for it to display to HTML, you have to use `<br />`. Alternatively, you can convert `\n` to `<br />` with the function `nl2br($text);`

Comment: you can use `PHP_EOL` for console output, for html - yep, you need '<br/>'-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing PHP code, you need to distinguish between two distinct concepts :

1. go to the new line in the code you produce, which you do using `"\n"`
2. go to the new line in the HTML webpage you produce, which you do using `<br />`

So, Option 1 makes you go to the new line in the code you produce, but you will not go to a new line in the HTML webpage you produce. The same way, option 2 makes you go to the new line in the HTML webpage you produce, but you will not go to a new line in the code you produce.

If you want go to the next line in **both** your code and the HTML output, you can just combine `"\n"` and `<br />` :

```
echo "<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

This essentially boils down to saving the below text to a HTML file and expecting it to have visual line breaks:

```
one line
another line
```

To have a visual line break in HTML you're gonna need the `br` element:

```
one line<br />
another line
```

So replace your `echo "\n";` with `echo '<br />';`.

If you have a string containing newlines, you could use the php built in `nl2br` to do the work for you:

```
<?php

$string = 'one line' . "\n" . 'another line';
echo nl2br($string);
```

Answer (score 3):

On echo, use `<br />`.

The `\n` won't work in the HTML page, only in the source code, executing the PHP from the command line or writing into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

On a web page, out of a `<pre>` block, all occurrences of tabs and newlines characters are assimilated as a single space.

For example:

```
echo "<pre>\n" . $selected_val . "</pre>";
```

But if your code is for debugging purposes, you'd better use `print_r` to inspect your variable values. Such as:

```
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars(print_r($select_val), true) . "</pre>";
```

The `htmlspecialchars` function preserving you from ill-formed HTML due to the variable content.

Comment: That's a valid explanation but that doesn't provide a solution. Please add a solution in your answer in order to address the problem.